# Where should the status of a long-running operation be stored?

Tags: java, spring

We have an operation (hereby named `check()`) built in our system. Upon starting this process, we would like to change the status of this resource from `Not Started` to `In Process`, and upon completion, to either `Failed` or `Successful`.

The current implementation is to write the corresponding status of said resource into DB. So the flow is like (provided a successful run):

> User clicked check -> `check()` started -> set status of the resource to `In Process` in DB-> `check()` finished -> set the status of the resource to `Successful` in DB

During `check()`, if a user clicks **Refresh** on the front end, a `GET` request to the corresponding resource will be fired, hence retrieving the current status (`In Process`) to be displayed to the user. If another user is trying to run `check()` on a resource that's currently `In Process`, the request should fail upon checking the status of the resource in DB.

Is this the correct solution to register a temporary status to the DB? I have a feeling that DB should be used to **persist** records instead of serving as a latch.

Comment: Well the row in the database represents the process, and the process has a state, that changes over time. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: If the operation result is data, then I would store the result of the operation in DB, not the status.
Another solution - you can create a web service to process the operation. It would register the result in your main system after process completion.
Your solution is ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) technique for this problem. Instead of storing the latest state of your process you can store series of state transitions as events.
For each incoming command (like check or refresh that you mentioned) you:

1. aggregate events that already happened to a process with a certain
   id, recreating the state of your process.
2. based on your business logic decide on the next state transition based on the current state and incoming command (this is some kind of a state-machine).
3. create a new event for a state transition and persist it in your event store.

To implement this kind of system correctly, don't forget about versioning your events. Here is a guide for versioning: [Versioning in an Event Sourced System](https://leanpub.com/esversioning/read)